# Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function _n

Tags: translation

I am getting this error?

> Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function
>   _n

can this be fixed? how can the translation be done in this case?

```
if( count($value) < $field['min'] ) {

        $valid = _n( '%s requires at least %s selection', '%s requires at least %s selections', $field['min'], 'acf' );
        $valid = sprintf( $valid, $field['label'], $field['min'] );

    }
```

UPDATE

The error is gone when `$field['min']` was assigned to a variable.  I am i doing it correct?

Comment: @Nicolai thanks!! error was exactly on this line `$valid = _n( '%s requires at least %s selection', '%s requires at least %s selections', $field['min'], 'acf' );` sorry but i am not able to understand your answer, may be a little explanation if possible :)

Comment: @Nicolai if i replace `$field['min']` with `$out` , then it shows no error.. `$out = $field['min']` ..but not sure why it worked

Comment: @Nicolai may be bacause asper 
 https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n  , Important: Never do a calculation inside the sprintf() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error (actually a warning) seems to come from the [Theme Check plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/).

There's nothing wrong with the code you're showing above. `'acf'` is your text domain. and the [_n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/) function takes four arguments as you've given it.

It strikes me that the Theme Check plugin is not very good at static analysis of function calls. I actually get a different warning with your code (possibly a later version) It seems it can't cope with array expressions like `$field['min']`. But of course WordPress/PHP will execute this just fine.

As you discovered yourself, assigning a variable gets rid of the warning. So doing something like the following is absolutely fine and seems to satisfy Theme Check's code scanner.

```
$n = $field['min'];
$valid = _n( '....', '....', $n, 'acf' );
$valid = sprintf( $valid, $field['label'], $n );
```

Comment: thanks, there seems to many other issues in detecting textdomains and understanding context where $echo to be escaped. and forcing to use to if class exist , there are cases where it is not possible to use that :/

Comment: The Theme Check is only intended to flag possible problems for you to investigate.